# Changing image inside element?

Tags: javascript, onclick, onchange

I haveve some function like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.close').click(function(){
     $(this).next(".firsttableheading").slideToggle();

     if($(this).text() == "-" ? $(this).text("+") : $(this).text("-"));
});     
 });
```

And html is

```
<a href="#" class="close" onClick="return false">
```

Evrything working ok, but i got problem when i want to put picture inside that a href, and change it on click

example i have image1.jpg and image2.jpg

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.close').click(function(){
     $(this).next(".firsttableheading").slideToggle();

     if($(this).img()  == "image1.jpg" ? $(this).img("image2.jpg") : $(this).img("image1.jpg"));
});     
 });
```

It is not working maybe i didnt get the element ok?

Comment: If you check the console, you should (probably) find that the element/object has no method `img()`, which is probably the problem. What HTML structure are you working with?

Comment: <h1Coca Cola</h1>
<a href="#" class="close" onClick="return false">-</a>

Comment: I don't remember jquery having .img function, maybe I am missing something over here, is this question tagged enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.close').click(function(){
         $(this).next(".firsttableheading").slideToggle();

         var img = $(this).find("img");
         img.attr("src")  == "image1.jpg" ? img.attr("src","image2.jpg") : img.attr("src","image1.jpg");
        });     
  });
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.close').click(function(){
             $(this).next(".firsttableheading").slideToggle();

             var img = $(this).find("img");
             img.attr('src', function(i,s){ 
                               return s == 'image1.jpg' ? 'image2.jpg' : 'image1.jpg'; });
            });     
      });
```

Comment: Rather than needlessly calling `attr()` multiple times I'd suggest using the anonymous function which contains a reference to the attribute you're working with: `img.attr('src', function(i,s){ return s == 'image1.jpg' ? 'image2.jpg' : 'image1.jpg'; });`